# MongoDB sorting documents by nested data

Tags: mongodb

Considering the following design for posts:

```
{
title: string,
body: string,
comments: [
    {name: string, comment: string, ...},
    {name: string, comment: string, ...},
    ...
]
}
...
```

1) I would like to select all posts in my collection and have them sorted by the posts that have the most comments. I'm assuming since the .length variable is always set via javascript that it is possible to use this to sort by but I don't know how or if it's actually more efficient to store the comment count in a field in the post document?

1.1) Or does it make more sense to store the comment count in a separate document and continiously update that?

2) When selecting posts, is it possible to limit the result to only return back the last 3 comments of a post document as opposed to the whole array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `aggregate` command

This should give you a list of post _id with the number of comments sorted by the count in reverse order.

You can use the $limit operators to return the x top rows. e.g.  `{ $limit : 5 }`

```
 db.posts.aggregate(
   { $unwind : "$comments" },
   { $group : { _id : "$_id" , number : { $sum : 1 } } },
   { $sort : { number : -1 } }
 );
```

Take a look
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/