# Mongodb How to sort nested using findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the data i have:

```
{
    "__v" : 25,
    "_id" : ObjectId("52aadd781a69bfb002000003"),
    "comments" : [
            {
                    "user" : ObjectId("52812042433e5cc012000002"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("52b2d134e5118e880a00000e"),
                    "created" : ISODate("2013-12-19T10:57:56.908Z"),
                    "comment" : "1"
            },
            {
                    "user" : ObjectId("52812042433e5cc012000002"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("52b2d151e5118e880a00000f"),
                    "created" : ISODate("2013-12-19T10:58:25.138Z"),
                    "comment" : "2"
            }
    ]
    }
```

And my code with findOne:

```
 db.products.findOne({},null,{sort:{'comments._id':-1}})
```

And the result is not descending which i wanted.

Comment: There are lots of questions like this already on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318526/mongodb-sorting-documents-by-nested-data

Comment: actually i using mongoose. It's can't work with populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` only sorts documents, not data in your document.

You could do `findOne` and then in your document:

```
doc.comments.sort(function (a, b) {
    var x = a._id;
    var y = b._id;
    // factor -1 because you want them sorted DESC
    return -1 * ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
});
```

If your client is not JavaScript, I'm sure you find a suitable way to sort the comments.

Comment: You're welcome! You could as well mark the answer as correct and/or helpful :)